# Failed Kasm Workspace installation on Ubuntu Server 23.10 LTS Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry

I was trying to install Kasm Workspace on Ubuntu Server 23.10 LTS and I received this error:

```
Setting Seed file as /opt/kasm/1.10.0/conf/database/seed_data/default_properties.yaml
yaml: unmarshal errors:
line 22: mapping key "restart" already defined at line 6 line 39: mapping key "restart" already defined at line 34
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: kasm_db: No such container: kasm_db
Error response from daemon: No such container: kasm_db
kasm_db_1.10. 0
kasm_db_1. 10.0
yaml: unmarshal errors:
line 22: mapping key "restart" already defined at line 6 line 39: mapping key "restart" already defined at line 34
```

I have not been able to resolve the problem.